# Unable to install WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager

Tags: tomcat7, wso2, wso2-iot

Hi i am unable to install the WSO2 Enterprise mobility Manager platform , followed the installation provided in the website, java environment variable is set, but getting error as below

```
[2014-05-02 11:27:41,150] ERROR {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -
[2014-05-02 11:27:41,151] ERROR {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -
[2014-05-02 11:27:41,151] ERROR {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -  Database is not confgured or has not started up
```

it is saying database is not configured, in the website they never mentioned about the database during the installation, can someone help me with this issue and als how to setup and database and run this platform.

Answer (score 0):

this issue arise with mysql database setup. please follow below listed link to sorted out that issue..

https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/General+Server+Configurations

there are few mistakes on documentation. On step 6, type exit;  and Step 9. add given config values within `<datasources> </datasources>`

Comment: hey can give more briefly about step 6 and 9

Comment: once you grant permission you need to exit from mysql console to run step 7. On step 9 they mentioned to update it, but if you search it you didn't found it on master-datasources.xml. you need to add those within datasources tag as i mentioned above.

Comment: i am using mysql command line client can u please let me know how to run step 7

Comment: just exit from mysql console using exit; command. then execute Step 7 on default shell.

Answer (score 0):

Please check using MySQL console whether the admin has permission to access EMM_DB. Meanwhile you can try WSO2 EMM 1.1.0 http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/